# OEM version of Windows 7 for a small company network

Tags: oem

I'm a web developer but I've been asked by a client (a real estate agency) to purchase and install Windows 7 on 3 of his machines.

I was wondering if it's OK to install an [OEM License and Media for System Builders version such as this one](http://www.ebuyer.com/259862-microsoft-windows-7-home-premium-w-sp1-licence-and-media-1-gfc-02021) on his machines? I've read in [this article](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/features/351598/how-to-buy-windows-7-for-50-less-the-truth-about-oem-versions/2) that Microsoft is OK with people buying those for computers they mount themselves, but in my case I am just installing Windows 7 on machines with XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but keep in mind:

- the OEM license was meant for a distributor
- that means YOU are expected to support it and deal with issues
- that also means that Microsoft will give a deaf ear to your users issues should they call
- ...and that beyond the standard patch/update stuff they provide, don't expect them to do much else